# Creating a circle with Leaflet (using a positive radius)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Making a circle in Leaflet seems pretty straight forward [according to the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle), you just supply coordinates, a radius and optionally an options object:

```
L.circle( <LatLng> latlng, <Number> radius, <Path options> options? )
```

I tried doing this on a map I was working on but only managed to produce a dot instead of a circle, no matter how large of a radius I specified. I let this drive me nuts for a while and then stepped away from the code to work on other projects.  I recently came back to it and on a whim I tried using a negative value for the radius:

```
"use strict";
var theMap = L.map("map", {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 7,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
  }).setView([0, 0], 0),
  eventsLayer = new L.LayerGroup(),

  unproject = function (coord) {
    return theMap.unproject(coord, theMap.getMaxZoom());
  },

  coord = unproject([12057.79, 13661.21]),

  southWest = unproject([0, 32768]),
  northEast = unproject([32768, 0]),

  radius = -8653.18, // Why isn't it working with a positive radius?!?!?
  circ = L.circle(coord, radius, {color: '#f00', fillColor: '#00f'});

theMap.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

L.tileLayer("https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/1/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg", {
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 7,
    continuousWorld: true
}).addTo(theMap);
eventsLayer.addTo(theMap);

theMap.setView(coord, 7, {animate: true});
circ.addTo(eventsLayer);
```

For some reason [it creates a circle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/8ev3mzjc/) with the negative radius.

This seems like a bug since the documentation uses a positive value for radii. Is there something I did wrong in my code that is causing this buggy behavior, or is it possibly a bug in Leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25042314/778975) I think it is a bug in Leaflet. I downloaded the current version of the dev master and [added into the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/0yssf3v8/).

```
radius = 1,
```

The new version does accept positive values and makes a circle. It is however buggy in a different way. 0.7 specifies that the radius to a circle should be set in meters. In the current dev version even a value of 1 covers hundreds of meters.